# Sign in with google using firebase auth doesn't work with me

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I want using sign in with google but it's don't work when i intent the accounts it's will be show but when i'm select one don't return data. I don't know why

in onCreate

```
     mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    // Initialize google Login tools
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken("454506450151-2ukiee0rjrv5ed7a6g1ua52qponeh8dd.apps.googleusercontent.com")
            .requestEmail()
            .build();


    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

    SignInButton signInButton = findViewById(R.id.login_with_google);
    signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //login with google
            loginWithGoogle();
        }
    });
```

This intent to show google accounts

```
    private void loginWithGoogle() {

    Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN_WITH_GOOGLE);
}
```

The problem is here in onActivityResult. the task isn't isSuccessful

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN_WITH_GOOGLE) {

        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);

        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

            GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult();
            if (account != null)
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);

        }else {

            ToastX.info(this, getString(R.string.error_happened)).show();

            Log.e("onActivityResult", "Google sign in failed");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Check your request Token it is correct or not? 

[check documentation] https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin

Comment: The token is correct

Comment: Add Log on activityresult and also wrap try catch to extract information. like on documentation.

Comment: I did same firebase documentation example code same thing not working. I tried make log to find the error and i found onActivityResult doesn't return data. Sorry to my English and i hope you can understand it